# Áccess VBA:How to get input in forms and use them in queries

Tags: ms-access, forms

HI

I have a form with a few buttons. Each button runs a few lines of code.the code have queries also in them like "select * from table where number =6"

now if i want to give the number as a input in the form, how do i go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add an unbound text control close to your button.
2. Update your button code to generate the query string as :

   "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myNumber =" & me.controls("myControlName").value
3. You might feel the need to make sure that the "myControlName" control allows only numbers/do not accept null, or treat all cases in your procedure

---

```
myQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
If Isnull(me.controls("myControlName").value) then
Else
    If isnumeric(me.controls("myControlName").value) then 
        myQuery = myQuery & " WHERE myNumber =" & me.controls("myControlName").value     
    Else 
        msgBox me.controls("myControlName").value & " is not accepted" 
        Exit function 
    Endif
Endif
```